# How to save reference for TemplateRef of component?

Tags: angular

Have template of component (test.component.ts):

test.component.html

```
<ng-template #template>
  <p>Content!</p>   
</ng-template>
```

In test.component.ts I want to have reference to corresponding template and have that reference saved. So, in component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
................................................
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private TestService: TestService) {}
  @ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
//here I am trying to save reference for template in service
//reference is saved when AfterViewInit takes place 
        this.TestService.setTemplate(this.template);
      }
}
```

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() {}
//setter-method for saving reference
  setTemplate(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.templateRef = template;
  }

//getter-method for getting reference for corresponding template

  getTemplate() {
    return this.templateRef;
  }
}
```

And in some moment I need to call some method of TestComponent from another component and get reference for the corresponding template:

```
   public someMethod() {

    .......................................
//here I am trying to get corresponding reference, but reference is undefined
        let template = this.alertService.getTemplate();
    .........................................

  }
```

Is it possible to have saved reference to the template that use it in any time?

Comment: probably a timing issue. `let template = this.alertService.getTemplate();` is being called before a reference is saved. So you can call that on later hook (ngAfterViewInit, ngAftercontentChecked) or`next` that ref to BehaviourSubject and subscribe later

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

> Race Condition

It happens when the Second component, where you are trying to access the Template Ref, is Constructed before the First component is ever created

## Solution

Only way to overcome the Race Condition, i.e Template Ref being undefined, is to use Event Emitters.

> **Event Emitters**:

```
export class TestService {
  public onTemplateRefChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() {}

  setTemplate(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.templateRef = template;
    this.onTemplateRefChange.emit(this.templateRef);
  }

  getTemplate() {
    return this.templateRef;
  }
}
```

> **Subscribe:**

```
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  templateSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.templateSubscription = this.testService.onTemplateRefChange.subscribe(templateRef => {
      this.templateRef = templateRef;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.templateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```